# DocumentDb query with both ordering and paging on the server side, possible?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing an API to allow a client to consume time-ordered data. There is a lot of it (10k+ records per client) so I don't want to dump all of it this back to the client and order there, hence my need to both order it and page it server-side. I have the paging working, but I cannot see how to add ordering.

I've seen recommendations to sort on the client, but given the potential amount of data that is not going to work in this case. Is there a workaround?

Here is what I have so far:

```csharp
var options = new FeedOptions {
    MaxItemCount = 25,
    RequestContinuation = continuationToken
}
var query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM TimelineEvent t WHERE t.acc_id = '{0}' AND t.removed != true", accountId); 
// ORDER BY in the query text doesn't appear to work
var events = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TimelineEvent>(colSelfLink, query, options).AsDocumentQuery();
var response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TimelineEvent>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box, but you can implement a stored procedure that does this.

The msft product group has supplied some code samples here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af/sourcecode?fileId=132409&pathId=34503205

Look under server side script, JS folder, you'll see an "orderby" script that does this. Adjust to your needs and try it.

Comment: BTW, this capability is planned, as published here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6334829--order-by-in-queries

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. I'll investigate further during the week.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY is now officially supported by DocumentDB

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-orderby/

Comment: Still no SKIP / TAKE though.